# How to unit test a repeated password in a form in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, unit-testing, symfony

I'm trying to unit test a form in my Symfony application. A normal form will work fine, but I cannot test when I have a repeated form type.

The test:

```
class MoniteurCreationTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = array(
            'username' => 'user',
            'plainPassword' => 'pass',
        );

        $type = new \AppBundle\Form\MoniteurCreationType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($type);
        $object = new Moniteur();

        $object->setUsername($formData['username']);
        $object->setPlainPassword($formData['password']);

        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

My Form Type:

```
class MoniteurCreationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Nom d\'utilisateur', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Insérez ici votre nom d\'utilisateur')))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Mot de passe', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Choisissez un mot de passe')),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Répéter le mot de passe', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Veuillez entrer encore une fois le mot de passe choisit')),
                    )
            )
            ->add('envoyer', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'col-lg-12  col-xs-12 btn btn-primary submit')))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Moniteur'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'moniteurCreation';
    }
}
```

The phpunit log:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\AppBundle\Form\MoniteurCreationTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'plainPassword' => null
-    'password' => 'pass'
+    'password' => null
     'email' => null
     'isActive' => null
     'derniereConnexion' => null
     'dateRecuperationMotDePasse' => null
 )

C:\web\www\testDoctrine\src\AppBundle\Tests\Form\MoniteurCreationTypeTest.php:29

FAILURES!
Tests: 8, Assertions: 60, Failures: 1.
```

All the other formy types word, but here I become a null in my unit test from the form. Do you knows why?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: One note - you don't have a field named `password` in your form - you shouldn't be checking against that, you should be checking against `plainPassword`

Comment: Yes, I have also tried this, but with the same error

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here.

- Your `$formData` variable is using a key of `password` when the key should be `plainPassword`, which is your field name in *MoniteurCreationType*
- This may not be the right place to test that values in your object are being set correctly - this seems like it would be better suited to a functional test.  The form unit tests are merely to test the operational capabilities of the form, not setting values
- The [RepeatedType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) is made up of two other fields, normally named `first` and `second`.  You can change those via the `first_name` and `second_name` options if you so chose.

If you really want to submit the proper data to your form, and then test that it has been set (if you `dump($form->getData());` you'll see it), then you will need to create your form data as follows:

```
$formData = array(
    'username' => 'user',
    'plainPasword' => array('first' => 'pass', 'second' => 'pass),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still receive the error:
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'username' => 'user'
-    'plainPassword' => 'user'
+    'plainPassword' => null
     'password' => null
     'email' => null
     'isActive' => null
     'derniereConnexion' => null
     'dateRecuperationMotDePasse' => null

Comment: I think you're testing the wrong things - you wouldn't use this unit test to test that your entity was updated with the data passed into your form (see my second bullet point).  This is for unit testing the form itself, not how it interacts with your objects.

Comment: reading your comment, I understand that. I think I do the wrong test, but I don't know how to do a better test?

Comment: The TestObject from the Symfony cookbook article - I cannot find that anywhere, and the original blog post the article was based on has no mention of it either.  If you want you could simply do `$this->assertEquals($formData, $form->getData());` and that would probably test everything you need.  From there you could get rid of your `$object` setting and assertion entirely.